# UITableViewCell accessoryView frame width/height zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, frame

I am trying to show a `UIPopoverController` from a `UITableViewCell` accessoryView when the accessory is tapped. I use:

```
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryView].frame inView:tableView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

But **the problem**: ...`accessoryView].frame` is `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}`, so the popover shows at the top left of the screen. Why does this happen? *How do I get the actual frame of the accessoryView?*

---

**I am using:**

- iOS 8
- Storyboards
- The predefined Detail Accessory (`UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton`)
- An iPad

Please let me know if you need any more code to answer, and I will try to get it for you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try showing it directly from the accessory view? If you aren't clipping the subviews of the cell this should work: `[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryView].frame inView:[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryView] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];`

Comment: @Raspu No, didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because `cell.accessoryView` is null.  `cell.accessoryView` only returns custom `accessoryView`.

Answer (score 0):

The frame of the `accessoryView` in within the `UITableViewCell` coordinate system. You need to convert it to the TableView coordinate system using a method on UIView: `-convertRect:fromView:`.

Call `[tableView convertRect:accessoryView.frame fromView:cell] // Code not tested`

Answer (score 0):

I never got the frame or bounds for the accessoryView, but this combination ultimately allowed me to fake it and got what I needed. A position near the right of the row (i.e. accessoryButton that updates the popover location after rotate.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   StackPropertiesTableViewController *stackPropertiesTableViewController = [[StackPropertiesTableViewController alloc] init];
   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:stackPropertiesTableViewController];
   self.stackPropertiesPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
   [self.stackPropertiesPopoverController setDelegate:self];
   TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Works for faking the display from Info accessoryView, but doesn't update it's location after rotate
    CGRect contentViewFrame = cell.contentView.frame;
    CGRect popRect = CGRectMake(contentViewFrame.origin.x + contentViewFrame.size.width, contentViewFrame.size.height/2.0, 1, 1);
    [self.stackPropertiesPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:cell permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    // Need this so popover knows which row it's on after rotate willRepositionPopoverToRect
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

This is needed to update the position of the popover relative to the row width after rotate. Don't forget to declare UIPopoverControllerDelegate

```
- (void)popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect inView:(inout UIView *__autoreleasing *)view
{        
   if (self.stackPropertiesPopoverController == popoverController)
   {
      NSIndexPath *itemPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
      if (itemPath)
         {
           TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:itemPath];
           if (cell)
              {
                 CGRect contentViewFrame = cell.contentView.frame;
                 CGRect popRect = CGRectMake(contentViewFrame.origin.x + contentViewFrame.size.width, contentViewFrame.size.height/2.0, 1, 1);
                 *rect = popRect;
               }
          }
    }
}
```